# issue with customizing command prompt view

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have some confusion on customizing the command prompt.
I learned the command prompt and I want the prompt to have three lines like this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]

(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(directory here)

>
```

I tried doing this command but it doesn't work at all:

```
Prompt $V &^

prompt $P &^

prompt $G
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a command prompt and not the powershell?

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Powershell output would say Powershell at the top, not the windows version.

Comment: how exactly you want the prompt look like?

Comment: @Breadgrammer: I edited your question to make it more readable.  I also removed your secondary question about automatically running a command when you start the command prompt.  Please ask that as a new question.

Comment: @Scott Thanks! I just wondered about the $ because I only know that from the powershell.

Comment: Do you want the prompt to look like this? version - line-break - path - line-break - greater-than?

Comment: `prompt=$V$_$_$Cc$F$S2016...$_$_$P$_$_$G` Note that this prompt have _seven_ lines, not three...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
prompt $P$_$G
```

[image]

If you do want the Windows version:

```
prompt $V$_$P$_$G
```

[image]

And if you really want it *exactly* like in your question, with the copyright and extra line breaks, you want this:

```
prompt $V$_$_(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.$_$_$P$_$_$G
```

[image]

---

According to the the help (`prompt /?`), `$^` isn't supported.  The caret is typically used for line continuation and escaping in certain cases.

Below are the docs.  You'll see `$P` is Path, `$_` is carriage return and `$G` is Greater Than.  You can use a combination of these to get results like the 3 screenshots above.

> ```
> Changes the cmd.exe command prompt.
>
> PROMPT [text]
>
>   text    Specifies a new command prompt.
>
> Prompt can be made up of normal characters and the following special codes:
>
>   $A   & (Ampersand)
>   $B   | (pipe)
>   $C   ( (Left parenthesis)
>   $D   Current date
>   $E   Escape code (ASCII code 27)
>   $F   ) (Right parenthesis)
>   $G   > (greater-than sign)
>   $H   Backspace (erases previous character)
>   $L   < (less-than sign)
>   $N   Current drive
>   $P   Current drive and path
>   $Q   = (equal sign)
>   $S     (space)
>   $T   Current time
>   $V   Windows version number
>   $_   Carriage return and linefeed
>   $$   $ (dollar sign)
>
> If Command Extensions are enabled the PROMPT command supports
> the following additional formatting characters:
>
>   $+   zero or more plus sign (+) characters depending upon the
>        depth of the PUSHD directory stack, one character for each
>        level pushed.
>
>   $M   Displays the remote name associated with the current drive
>        letter or the empty string if current drive is not a network
>        drive.
> ```

Comment: I think what he wants is `prompt $V$_$P$_$G`

Comment: I assumed the version was just from him opening a new command prompt, but it does make his "three lines" comment make more sense. I'll update my answer.

Comment: `$V` doesn't include the copyright info, so it was from opening the command prompt.  Updated with a few options anyway.

Comment: Prompt also accepts regular strings, so you could conceivably just type that bit in manually.

Comment: lol I guess that's true, but... updated to include it for funsies!

Comment: thank's this fixed my issue! that's exactly how i wanted it to be pic #2